# How can I import data from excel?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to progress and I would like to know if there is a way to import data from excel. So far I have done only for CSV. Please share your Exp here!!! I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the easiest way for you is to save the excel sheet as CSV and then simply import that. If that's not possible you could take a look at automation of excel to perhaps trigger a Save AS CSV and then import that.

[Here's a quite good example in the KnowledgeBase](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/21671). Please note that there might be changes due to different versions of Excel (also possibly of Progress).

There might also be DotNet APIs that might help you. Look for those in Microsofts documentation in that case.